# Visual Studio: Tab key selects and highlights code

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

If I place my cursor inside a multi-line comment:

```
/*
 * place cursor after the asterisk and before the word 'place'
 */
if (x == 0) 
{
    // some code
}
```

... and hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, Visual Studio doesn't add whitespace as usual.  Instead, it highlights the entire comment (all three lines, in the example).  If I hit <kbd>tab</kbd> again, it will select and highlight the next statement or block of statements.  In my example, it highlights the entire `if`.

How do I fix this and make Visual Studio tab things over?  I want <kbd>tab</kbd> to behave like a <kbd>tab</kbd>.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Resharper 9.  It started doing this yesterday, and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Figured it out.  It wasn't in VS' settings!  Somehow Resharper's configuration was changed.  In Resharper's settings:

```
Environment > Editor > Editor Behavior
```

Uncheck the box labeled "Structural Navigation".  Click "Save".

Comment: Why would anybody want "tab" to turn into a select/highlight block operation?  Furthermore, what are you *losing* by unchecking Structural Navigation? Surely it's not a synonym for "toggle ridiculous tab behavior inside comment blocks".

Comment: I have no idea, but I feel the same way.  Of all the features my IDE has with Resharper, this one appears to be the most useless.

Comment: It's so annoying, they allow you to disable it when: caret is at start of line, end of line, in comment, or code is selected... so what's left?! See [ReSharper help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Navigation_and_Search_Structural_Navigation.html). @Rick O'Shea

Comment: This happened magically to me. There must be a hot key to enable/disable it and it was enabled accidentally. Very annoying.

Comment: ReSharper, you can do whatever with at least one extra modifier key (Ctrl, Alt, even Shift). Just leave plain tab with its own func.

Comment: Annoying "feature". Thanks.

Comment: This happened to me again... 2 years later and found my old comment.

Comment: I've had this mis-feature turned off for years and the latest Resharper update just turned it back on again.  Ugh.